# How to authenticate sharepoint claims based web application from farm based authentication enabled asp.net application or asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, sharepoint-2010

How to authenticate to share point claims based web application from an asp.net web application.

1)  i have a sharepoint web application which is (windows) claims based authentication enable and its in  domain for example: COMPANY1

```
- and its not enable anonymous access , only a share point group can lo-gin to this share point site( these users are belongs to a  A.D group).
```

2)In  another domain COMPANY 2:

i have simple asp.net application which is farm authentication enable and users authenticated to this application from sql server database( users saved ins sql server ).

scenario:

Users will login to asp.net application and authenticated , and after they will view the dashboard of this application in home page(default.aspx page)

and after here in this page there is a link to view the some BI data ( that exists in Sharepoint website)

here when this authenticated user clicks this link it must be open shaepoint page without asking

login credentials.

this is how its possible to do in sharepoint 2010

when i research about my problem i found that create custom sts service in sharepoint

and after  how to make authentication between asp.net and sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446525.aspx

A little dated information but think the scenario falls into what you need to setup for groups and claims on respective account.  Tokens (jwt or swt) are generally used as part of the authorization process